# Domain in Google Domains and Code in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

Before you read the rest I am an absolute beginner at deploying website and the end goal would be:

My website I want to load is

```
site.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

and I want all the content to be put on

```
mydomain.com
```

So when you visit mydomain.com you see see all the content that is supposed to be on the AWS S3 Site.

I have followed many articles and posts, however I don't seem to be getting the expected results or they seem to be outdated.

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)?

Comment: @DusanBajic I have tried but maybe I did a step wrong twice. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to migrate to route 53.

However, you can set up a redirect or simply set up an [CNAME record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/86167?hl=en) that resolves to S3 Static website URL.

The last step is to [Forward](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en) domain to your naked domain name "example.com" to "www.example.com

NOTE: You could just Forward to your bucket using the complete bucket URL with "name masking", however most web crawlers will not see your complete site if you do it that way and web searches will fail.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The S3 bucket name *must* be the same as the domain name, so your bucket should be called `mydomain.com`. Then just add a cname in your DNS to resolve to mydomain.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com